# VC6 setting additional include path using env vars?

Tags: preprocessor, environment-variables, visual-c++-6

I can't believe I am asking this...

It has been a while since I used VC6.  I set up what I thought was the correct way to include additional directories for include files (I removed another developer's hard coded paths) and put in something like:

%MY_DIR%\include

but this does not work.  Am I missing something?  Did VC6 not allow this?  It seems like a pretty basic thing to have and now that I think about it it I can't recall ever having done it before...

(I did stop and re-start VC6 after I set the variables)

Google search and a quick search here did not reveal anything.

EDIT

Apparently I can't vote for my own answer - but it is below:

The syntax is:

$(ENV_VAR)

not

%ENV_VAR%

---

I'd rather not have to add to an include env variable - that seems to imply that I have to build from a command line now.  I want to be able to add an environment variable in the project settings.  That seems like a very simple thing to do, but perhaps that was expecting too much from the IDE team.

I am not sure what it means that %MY_DIR% is not taken into account properly...  I did start cmd.exe from the tools menu like you suggested and the env path I set is there and as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer...

it works fine.

$(ENV_VAR_NAME)
not
%ENV_VAR_NAME%

(I feel like an idiot. )

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the IDE will take any environment settings unless you use that flag.

Oh, and you don't *have* build from the command line if you launch it from the command line. You can still use the build menu in the IDE.

Comment: It does not work.  I started msdev /useenv and I get the same results.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think Ferruccio's first answer is probably best, have you tried that one?